# How do I parse a string using the split method but with 2 different delimiters in java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, split

I'm trying to have the user input a polynomial like  4x+3x-2x. I then want it to parse each terms into a String Array. I have it working, but my issue is that I can only do it with a + or a -, not a + and a -.

```
    //instance variables
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String polynomial = "";

    //takes in the polynomial
    System.out.println("Enter a polynomial");
    polynomial = scan.next();

    //print the polynomial
    System.out.println("\n" + "Your polynomial is "+ polynomial);   

    //parse the polynomial into a StringArray
    String[] polyArray = polynomial.split("\\-");
```

<--------- how do I make this part accept a plus or a minus, not just a minus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split *on* plus/minus, which *consumes* the delimiters:

```
String[] polyArray = polynomial.split("[-+]");
```

If to want to split *before/after plus/minus, which *preserves* the operators as their own String, you need a regex that doesn't consume them:

```
String[] polyArray = polynomial.split("(?=[-+])|(?<=[-+])");
```

This last regex uses *look arounds*, which assert but don't consume the input (they are zero-width matches).